# OS X PPD Picker

Tags: macos, printing, drivers, cups

I would like to implement a PPD Picker similar to the one done by apple accessible from the Printing Preference Panel.

[image]

Are there any APIs available to do this? If there aren't any APIs available do you know how I can get the information in the tables?

Answer (score -1):

In /etc/cups there is a file called ppd that lists all ppd drivers that are installed.  The printers.conf file contains all the information on each of these printers such as makemodel, state, etc.  You need to be logged in as root to view most of this information.

CUPS API has a lot of different functions that accesses these files and returns the information contained in these files.

This is the main documentation page that contains information on everything CUPS:

http://www.cups.org/documentation.php?VERSION=1.7&INDEX=0&Q=

This is the intro to CUPS programming page that has some sample code:

http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/doc-1.7/api-overview.html

Comment: In /etc/cups there is a *folder* called ppd and it contains a ppd file for every mapped printer. I want a list of all drivers installed on the system so the user can pick one and it will be later mapped to a printer.

Comment: PPD files are the basis of all printer drivers in CUPS.  Each driver in cups consist of a PPD file and other filter programs.  Therefore to get your list of drivers, this is where you would go.  There is also another folder that may contain printer drivers at /usr/share/cups, but /etc/cups/ppd is the main one.  Maybe you are trying to access available printer drivers on a shared network or something?

Comment: I want a list of available printer drivers installed on the machine so the user can pick a PPD from the ones available and then my program will automate configurations.